# How do I declare this text containing quotes as a string in VB?

Tags: vb.net

Here is the text I need to declare as a variable:

```
{ "isReadOnly": false, "sku": "393A0001", "clientVersion": 3, "nuc": 2315038076, "nucleusPersonaId": 232865288, "nucleusPersonaDisplayName": "McFux", "nucleusPersonaPlatform": "360", "locale": "en-GB", "method": "idm", "priorityLevel":4, "identification": { "EASW-Token": "" } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes to escape the quotes in the string.

For example:

```
Dim s = "{ ""isReadOnly"": false, ""sku"": ..."
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I prefer to use a function to add quotes to a string, purely for readability, especially when building a string from variables.

```
Function Qt(Byval str as String) as String

    Return """" & str & """"

End Function
```

That way `"{ """ & isReadOnly & """: false, """ & sku & """: ..."` becomes:

```
"{ " & Qt(isReadOnly) & ": " & false & ", " & Qt(sku) & ": ..."
```

Answer (score 1):

In VB, you double up the quotes to escape them:

```
"{ ""isReadOnly"": false, ""sku"": ""393A0001"", ..."
```

Answer (score 0):

To escape a quote you just need to add another quote.

="{ ""isReadOnly""}"